# avr-gcc compilation? Can someone help me

Tags: c, gcc, avr

I have a problem when I compile my code, it shows errors like :

```
main.c:33:5: warning: 'PORTE_INT0_vect' appears to be a misspelled signal handler
 ISR(PORTE_INT0_vect)
     ^
In file included from main.c:8:0:
main.h:15:19: error: 'PORTE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define DATA_PORT PORTE``
                   ^
main.c:35:11: note: in expansion of macro 'DATA_PORT'
   inbit = DATA_PORT.IN & DATA_PIN;
           ^
main.h:15:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define DATA_PORT PORTE
                   ^
main.c:35:11: note: in expansion of macro 'DATA_PORT'
   inbit = DATA_PORT.IN & DATA_PIN;
```

I write this on terminal :

```
avr-gcc -g -Os -mmcu=atmega32 -c main.c
```

Can someone help me please and tell me what is the problem? I am new with aver so I dont understand anything about this errors.
Sorry my english sucks.

so this is the code :

```
main.h
    #ifndef MAIN_H
    #define MAIN_H

    #include "ax25.h"
    #ifdef DEBUG
    #include "debug.h"
    #endif

    #define TRUE 1
    #define FALSE 0

    #define CLK_PORT PORTA
    #define DATA_PORT PORTA
    #define CLK_PIN PIN2_bm
    #define DATA_PIN PIN0_bm
    #define USART_PORT PORTC
    #define USART USARTC0

    /* States for the communication system */
    enum states
      {
        CW_STATE,
        RX_STATE,
        TX_STATE,
        TX_TEST_STATE
      };

    /* G3RUH scramble */
    #define SCRAMBLE TRUE

    /* Addresses, 6 ascii charaters, pad with white spaces */
    #define SENDER "CBSTAR"
    #define RECEIVER "EARTH"

    /* Size of ring buffer for packets */
    /* Must be of 2^n size */
    #define RB_SIZE 8
    #define TX_RB_SIZE 256
    #define RX_RB_SIZE 256

    #define USART_SIZE 258 
    /* Data buffer for receiving USART data */
    typedef struct USART_BUFFER
    {
      uint8_t buffer[USART_SIZE];
      uint16_t ptr;
    }USART_BUFFER_t;

    /* Ring buffer for buffering several packets prior to sending
     */
    typedef struct TX_RING_BUFFER
    {
      uint8_t buffer[TX_RB_SIZE * RB_SIZE];
      uint8_t count;
      uint8_t buffer_fill;
      uint8_t *head;
      uint8_t *tail;
      uint8_t *temp;
    } TX_RING_BUFFER_t;

    /* Ring buffer for buffering several received frames */
    typedef struct RX_RING_BUFFER
    {
      uint8_t buffer[RX_RB_SIZE * RB_SIZE];
      uint8_t count;
      uint8_t *head;
      uint8_t *tail;
    }RX_RING_BUFFER_t;

    /* Register for keeping frame configuration settings */
    typedef struct FRAME_CONFIGURATION
    {
      uint8_t delay;
      uint8_t preamble;
      uint8_t add_head;
      uint8_t add_tail;
    }FRAME_CONFIGURATION_t;

    /* Protocol identifiers for the CubeSTAR protocol */
    /* Can be extended to other packet types here, e.g. ACK/NACK
     */
    enum commands
      {
        CMD = 0x10, // command frames
        HK = 0x20, // housekeeping frames
        TEST = 0x30, // test frames
        PAYLOAD = 0x40, //payload data frames
        RAW = 0x50 // raw ascii frames
      };

    /* Function declarations */
    void initialize();

    void add_byte(RX_BUFFER_t *buf);
    void handle_rx_buffer(RX_RING_BUFFER_t *rx_rb);
    void handle_data(RX_BUFFER_t *buf, RX_FRAME_t *frame);

    void init_clk();
    void init_usart();
    void config_frame(uint8_t preamble, uint8_t head, uint8_t tail, uint8_t delay);
    void create_frame(enum commands id, uint8_t *data, uint8_t size);
    void send_frame();
    void resend_frames();
    void bang_out(TX_BUFFER_t *buf);
    void byte_out(uint8_t byte);
    void bit_out(uint8_t bit);

    void tx_ring_buffer_init(TX_RING_BUFFER_t *tx_rb);
    uint8_t tx_ring_buffer_push(TX_RING_BUFFER_t *tx_rb, const uint8_t *tx_data);
    uint8_t tx_ring_buffer_pop(TX_RING_BUFFER_t *tx_rb, uint8_t *tx_data);
    void tx_ring_buffer_reset(TX_RING_BUFFER_t *tx_rb);
    void tx_ring_buffer_set(TX_RING_BUFFER_t *tx_rb);
    void rx_ring_buffer_init(RX_RING_BUFFER_t *rx_rb);
    uint8_t rx_ring_buffer_push(RX_RING_BUFFER_t *rx_rb, uint8_t *rx_data);
    uint8_t rx_ring_buffer_pop(RX_RING_BUFFER_t *rx_rb, uint8_t *rx_data);

    void usart_buffer_clr();
    void from_usart();

    void test_frame(uint8_t preamble, uint8_t head, uint8_t tail,
            uint8_t delay, uint8_t data, uint8_t frames_lo, uint8_t
            frames_hi);
    void test_frame_command(enum commands id, uint8_t data_length);
    void test_1(uint8_t data, uint8_t frames_lo, uint8_t frames_hi);
    void set_state(uint8_t next_state);

    #endif
```

it is not my personal code, Im just using it for a project. this is all the errors I get.

```
In file included from main.c:3:0:
main.c: In function 'PORTA_INT0_vect':
main.c:33:5: warning: 'PORTA_INT0_vect' appears to be a misspelled signal handler
 ISR(PORTA_INT0_vect)
     ^
In file included from main.c:8:0:
main.h:15:19: error: 'PORTE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define DATA_PORT PORTE
                   ^
main.c:35:11: note: in expansion of macro 'DATA_PORT'
   inbit = DATA_PORT.IN & DATA_PIN;
           ^
main.h:15:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define DATA_PORT PORTE
                   ^
main.c:35:11: note: in expansion of macro 'DATA_PORT'
   inbit = DATA_PORT.IN & DATA_PIN;
           ^
main.h:17:18: error: 'PIN0_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define DATA_PIN PIN0_bm
                  ^
main.c:35:26: note: in expansion of macro 'DATA_PIN'
   inbit = DATA_PORT.IN & DATA_PIN;
                          ^
In file included from main.c:3:0:
main.c: In function 'USARTC0_RXC_vect':
main.c:39:5: warning: 'USARTC0_RXC_vect' appears to be a misspelled signal handler
 ISR(USARTC0_RXC_vect)
     ^
In file included from main.c:8:0:
main.h:19:15: error: 'USARTC0' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define USART USARTC0
               ^
main.c:41:16: note: in expansion of macro 'USART'
   usart_data = USART.DATA;
                ^
main.c: In function 'init_usart':
main.c:170:13: error: request for member 'DIRCLR' in something not a structure or union
   USART_PORT.DIRCLR = PIN2_bm;
             ^
main.c:170:23: error: 'PIN2_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART_PORT.DIRCLR = PIN2_bm;
                       ^
main.c:171:13: error: request for member 'DIRSET' in something not a structure or union
   USART_PORT.DIRSET = PIN3_bm;
             ^
main.c:171:23: error: 'PIN3_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART_PORT.DIRSET = PIN3_bm;
                       ^
In file included from main.c:8:0:
main.h:19:15: error: 'USARTC0' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define USART USARTC0
               ^
main.c:174:3: note: in expansion of macro 'USART'
   USART.BAUDCTRLA = 51; /* 19200 bps @ 6 MHz clock */
   ^
main.c:177:18: error: 'USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART.CTRLC |= USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc | USART_CMODE_ASYNCHRONOUS_gc | USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc;
                  ^
main.c:177:41: error: 'USART_CMODE_ASYNCHRONOUS_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART.CTRLC |= USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc | USART_CMODE_ASYNCHRONOUS_gc | USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc;
                                         ^
main.c:177:71: error: 'USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART.CTRLC |= USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc | USART_CMODE_ASYNCHRONOUS_gc | USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc;
                                                                       ^
main.c:179:18: error: 'USART_RXCINTLVL0_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART.CTRLA |= USART_RXCINTLVL0_bm;
                  ^
main.c:180:3: error: 'PMIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
   PMIC.CTRL |= PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm;
   ^
main.c:180:16: error: 'PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   PMIC.CTRL |= PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm;
                ^
main.c:181:18: error: 'USART_RXEN_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART.CTRLB |= USART_RXEN_bm | USART_TXEN_bm;
                  ^
main.c:181:34: error: 'USART_TXEN_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   USART.CTRLB |= USART_RXEN_bm | USART_TXEN_bm;
                                  ^
In file included from main.c:8:0:
main.c: In function 'bit_out':
main.h:14:18: error: 'PORTE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define CLK_PORT PORTE
                  ^
main.c:355:12: note: in expansion of macro 'CLK_PORT'
    while(!(CLK_PORT.IN & CLK_PIN));
            ^
main.h:16:17: error: 'PIN2_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define CLK_PIN PIN2_bm
                 ^
main.c:355:26: note: in expansion of macro 'CLK_PIN'
    while(!(CLK_PORT.IN & CLK_PIN));
                          ^
main.c: In function 'handle_data':
main.h:19:15: error: 'USARTC0' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define USART USARTC0
               ^
main.c:373:13: note: in expansion of macro 'USART'
    while(!((USART.STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm) !=0));
             ^
main.c:373:28: error: 'USART_DREIF_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
    while(!((USART.STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm) !=0));
                            ^
main.c: In function 'init_clk':
main.c:557:3: error: 'OSC' undeclared (first use in this function)
   OSC.XOSCCTRL = OSC_FRQRANGE_2TO9_gc | OSC_XOSCSEL_EXTCLK_gc;
   ^
main.c:557:18: error: 'OSC_FRQRANGE_2TO9_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)
   OSC.XOSCCTRL = OSC_FRQRANGE_2TO9_gc | OSC_XOSCSEL_EXTCLK_gc;
                  ^
main.c:557:41: error: 'OSC_XOSCSEL_EXTCLK_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)
   OSC.XOSCCTRL = OSC_FRQRANGE_2TO9_gc | OSC_XOSCSEL_EXTCLK_gc;
                                         ^
main.c:558:15: error: 'OSC_XOSCEN_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   OSC.CTRL |= OSC_XOSCEN_bm;
               ^
main.c:559:25: error: 'OSC_XOSCRDY_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   while ( (OSC.STATUS & OSC_XOSCRDY_bm) == 0);
                         ^
main.c:560:3: error: 'CCP' undeclared (first use in this function)
   CCP=0xD8;
   ^
main.c:561:3: error: 'CLK' undeclared (first use in this function)
   CLK.CTRL = CLK_SCLKSEL_XOSC_gc;
   ^
main.c:561:14: error: 'CLK_SCLKSEL_XOSC_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)
   CLK.CTRL = CLK_SCLKSEL_XOSC_gc;
              ^
main.c:562:16: error: 'OSC_RC2MEN_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   OSC.CTRL &= ~OSC_RC2MEN_bm;
                ^
In file included from main.c:8:0:
main.c: In function 'initialize':
main.h:14:18: error: 'PORTE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define CLK_PORT PORTE
                  ^
main.c:573:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CLK_PORT'
     CLK_PORT.DIRCLR = CLK_PIN;
     ^
main.h:16:17: error: 'PIN2_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define CLK_PIN PIN2_bm
                 ^
main.c:573:23: note: in expansion of macro 'CLK_PIN'
     CLK_PORT.DIRCLR = CLK_PIN;
                       ^
main.c: In function 'set_state':
main.h:15:19: error: 'PORTE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define DATA_PORT PORTE
                   ^
main.c:606:7: note: in expansion of macro 'DATA_PORT'
       DATA_PORT.DIRCLR = DATA_PIN;
       ^
main.h:17:18: error: 'PIN0_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define DATA_PIN PIN0_bm
                  ^
main.c:606:26: note: in expansion of macro 'DATA_PIN'
       DATA_PORT.DIRCLR = DATA_PIN;
                          ^
main.c:607:26: error: 'PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
       CLK_PORT.INTCTRL = PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm;
                          ^
In file included from main.c:8:0:
main.h:16:17: error: 'PIN2_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define CLK_PIN PIN2_bm
                 ^
main.c:608:27: note: in expansion of macro 'CLK_PIN'
       CLK_PORT.INT0MASK = CLK_PIN;
                           ^
main.c:609:27: error: 'PORT_ISC_RISING_gc' undeclared (first use in this function)
       CLK_PORT.PIN2CTRL = PORT_ISC_RISING_gc;
                           ^
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:657:3: error: 'PMIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
   PMIC.CTRL = PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm;
   ^
main.c:657:15: error: 'PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm' undeclared (first use in this function)
   PMIC.CTRL = PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm;
```

and finally this a part of main.c , the code is too long

```
main.c
#define F_CPU 8000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

/* AX.25 UI frame info and buffers */
TX_FRAME_t tx_frame;
TX_BUFFER_t tx_buffer;
RX_BUFFER_t rx_buffer;
RX_FRAME_t rx_frame;
FRAME_CONFIGURATION_t frame_configuration;

TX_RING_BUFFER_t tx_packet_buffer;
RX_RING_BUFFER_t rx_packet_buffer;
USART_BUFFER_t usartrx_buffer;

/* Global declarations */
volatile uint8_t current_state;
volatile uint8_t inbit;
volatile uint8_t usart_data;
volatile uint8_t frame_counting;
volatile uint8_t frames_to_resend;

/* For testing only */
volatile uint16_t num_test_frames;
volatile uint8_t cont_test_frames;
volatile uint8_t num_test_data;

ISR(PORTE_INT0_vect)
{
  inbit = DATA_PORT.IN & DATA_PIN;
  add_bit(inbit, &rx_frame, &rx_buffer, SCRAMBLE);
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to add some code snippets so we can get a better idea of what is going on :)

Comment: I just posted it as an answer for my question

Answer (score 1):

The code you are trying to compile was written for an ATxmega128. This is a completely different line of microcontroller from the ATmega32 you're using, and does not have the same peripherals. For instance, the ATmega32 only has GPIO ports PORTA through PORTD, and entirely lacks the programmable multi-level interrupt controller (PMIC).

This code will require significant changes to run on your microcontroller, if it is possible at all. This is probably not a good introductory project for you.

Comment: If you have an Atmega32, then you need to use another port. If you have a different chip with PORTE, then you need to set the compiler parameter to be the correct processor. This is probably some tab in the IDE if you are using one.

Comment: So I have just to change PORTE for PORTA or PORTB for exemple? 
what about the other errors?

Comment: The other errors are mostly because the Atmega32 doesn't have them. You have to determine what processor you have, and what your processor has. (If you are going to use PORTB, then you need to connect the wires to the correct pins, for example.) The datasheet for the processor has all the correct spellings of the terms.